# How to get "2016-05-11" in Masa attributes

Tags: laravel-5

[image: Database image]

Here is the query I run:

```
$table1 = DB::table('diaris')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute like this:

```
$record = DB::table('diaris')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$record->masa; // <-- accessing the property
```

Comment: the output still the same. Im looking the exact output which is "2016-05-11" . Right now the output still " 2016-05-10'

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you need to update the date?

Comment: Or do you want to select the second record?